Laravel PowerGrid is not applying the styles correctly
so I am having a bit of a trouble with PowerGrid.. it is not applying the styles and looks messy.

This is my app.js
import './../../vendor/power-components/livewire-powergrid/dist/tailwind.css'
import './../../vendor/power-components/livewire-powergrid/dist/powergrid'
import './bootstrap';
import 'flowbite';

This is my view
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('content')
<div class="space-y-6">
    <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold">Welcome to {{ config('app.name') }}</h2>
    <p class="text-gray-700">
        Here you can view all your currently existing cronjobs.
    </p>

    <!-- PowerGrid Table for Cronjobs, outside of any card or container -->
     @include('livewire.cronjob-power-grid')
</div>
@endsection

Inside the powergrid config I chose the tailwindcss theme. I installed tailwindcss using the documentation from the tailwind homepage

It would be good if the users can see a live output so that they can debug and let you know the solution.
